# Recyclerview inside recyclerview dpad navigation not working on android tv

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, television

I created one recyclerview inside that recyclerview each row have a horizontal recyclerview. Now when I try to move through child recyclerview(horizontal recyclerview) I am not able to do. I added the requestfocus and focusable= true.
Still not able to get the focus.

Answer (score 0):

try putting the following on the `recyclerviews`

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterdescendants"
```